# Wireshark - TCP SYN, SYN ACK and acknowledgement number from server

Tags: tcp, wireshark, ack, syn

I have a trace like the shown in the pictures bellow:
[image]
[image]

I want to know the raw sequence number from the segment TCP SYN (1), the raw sequence number from the SYN ACK (2) and the acknowledgement number from the server (3).

By expanding the layer 3, I got the following information:

```
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 60843, Dst Port: 80, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0
    Source Port: 60843
    Destination Port: 80
    [Stream index: 8]
    [TCP Segment Len: 0]
    Sequence Number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    Sequence Number (raw): 2241567664
    [Next Sequence Number: 2    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment Number: 1    (relative ack number)
    Acknowledgment number (raw): 2536056279
    0101 .... = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Flags: 0x011 (FIN, ACK)
    Window: 513
    [Calculated window size: 513]
    [Window size scaling factor: -1 (unknown)]
    Checksum: 0x1fec [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    Urgent Pointer: 0
    [Timestamps]
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to find all the parameters I'm looking for.

Answer 1 -> ???

Answer 2 -> Sequence Number (raw): 2241567664

Answer 3 -> Acknowledgment number (raw): 2536056279

Is this right? Could you please let me know which ones are the correct values for each questions (1,2 and 3)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but if you click "Transmission Control Protocol" you can see in Flags the TCP SYN

[image]